# TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I'm trying to compute the cosine similarity between 350k sentences using tensorflow.

My sentences are first vectorisd using sklearn:

```
doc =  df['text']
vec = TfidfVectorizer(binary=False,norm='l2',use_idf=False,smooth_idf=False,lowercase=True,stop_words='english',min_df=1,max_df=1.0,max_features=None,ngram_range=(1, 1))
X = vec.fit_transform(doc)
print(X.shape)
print(type(X))
```

This works very well and I get sparse matrix back, I have then tried in two ways to convert my sparse matrix to a dense one.

(1) I tried this:

```
dense = X.toarray()
```

This only works with a small amount of data (around 10k sentences), but then fails on the actual computation.

(2) I have been trying to convert the output `X`  this way, but get the same error message when doing the first step `K`:

```
K = tf.convert_to_tensor(X, dtype=None, dtype_hint=None, name=None)
Y = tf.sparse.to_dense(K, default_value=None, validate_indices=True, name=None)
```

Any tips/ tricks to solve this mystery would be greatly appreciated. Also happy to consider batching my computations if that should be more efficient in terms of size?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a TensorFlow sparse matrix from your SciPy one. Since your matrix seems to be in CSR format, you can do it as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
import tensorflow as tf

def sparse_csr_to_tf(csr_mat):
    indptr = tf.constant(csr_mat.indptr, dtype=tf.int64)
    elems_per_row = indptr[1:] - indptr[:-1]
    i = tf.repeat(tf.range(csr_mat.shape[0], dtype=tf.int64), elems_per_row)
    j = tf.constant(csr_mat.indices, dtype=tf.int64)
    indices = np.stack([i, j], axis=-1)
    data = tf.constant(csr_mat.data)
    return tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices, data, csr_mat.shape)

# Test
m = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix([
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 3, 4],
], dtype=np.float32)
tf_mat = sparse_csr_to_tf(m)
tf.print(tf.sparse.to_dense(tf_mat))
# [[0 0 1 0]
#  [0 0 0 0]
#  [2 0 3 4]]
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately your solution throws another error message on the line tf_mat = sparce_csr_to_tf(m): "NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (Repeat/boolean_mask/GatherV2:0) to a numpy array" - just to clarify I have tried to feed in my matrix X from the example above, right?

Comment: @msa Well, this just converts the CSR sparse matrix into a TensorFlow sparse matrix, if you want to come back to NumPy later you would need to use `.numpy()` (on the dense tensor, assuming you are on eager mode). However, if the problem is that the resulting matrix is too big for your system, I don't think using TensorFlow will help with it...